# Change user's home directory to udev partition on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, user-profile

I have AWS EC2 instance and its disk usage always above 90% and just trying to move user folder to "udev" partition to free disk space.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  6.7G  830M  90% /
udev            3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
```

First question I know what is this partition and used for but if i move user's folder to it, Is there any harm?

Second, I just did following steps. But i can't connect to server with ssh after restart server. Any solution and explanation to it?

```
sudo mv /home/ubuntu /dev/ubuntu
sudo mkdir /home/ubuntu
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu
mount --bind --verbose /dev/ubuntu /home/ubuntu
```

---

### UPDATE 2

---

OK i think problem is solved. The reason of error is caused by moving user home folder to /dev. It was big mistake because udev partition is placed on memory.  When i stop server, computer's memory will cleared out. Which means my user folder will gone forever.

Thanks for quick response time and great content. Really appreciate that.

Comment: When you say can't connect what exactly is the error message you get.

Comment: If that's what you did and then rebooted the server, you just wiped out your /home/ubuntu.  udev is not a standard filesystem, it's a device manager stored entirely in RAM.  You reboot, your RAM is cleared.  [This answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/a/675664/237790) will explain more.

Comment: i really want to vote up your comment but my reputation is not enough. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The udev device is a RAM disk and so unfortunately I think you have just lost all your data from /home/ubuntu.

See this [Answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/675568/shrink-or-delete-udev-partition-in-ubuntu/675664#675664) for more details on udev

Best reach for your backups to get that back.

---

If you tell us the exact message you get from your ssh connection attempts we ma be ale to help you out there but that may be immaterial.

Comment: So if i move home folder to dev partition means i'm placing it on memory?

Comment: OK figured it out. This means i'm plaing it on memory.

Comment: Marking as accepted answer. Will  be appreciate if you include yoonix's link to it. Thanks.